# NSCalendar set firstWeekDay to monday but results are different

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nscalendar

I am trying to get the beginning date of a month.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"begining of month: %@ from today", [self beginningOfMonth:[NSDate date]]);
}

- (NSDate *)beginningOfMonth:(NSDate *)date {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    calendar.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    calendar.firstWeekday = 2;
    NSDateComponents *componentsCurrentDate = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitWeekday|NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth fromDate:date];

    NSDateComponents *componentsNewDate = [NSDateComponents new];

    componentsNewDate.year = componentsCurrentDate.year;
    componentsNewDate.month = componentsCurrentDate.month;
    componentsNewDate.weekOfMonth = 1;
    componentsNewDate.weekday = calendar.firstWeekday;

    return [calendar dateFromComponents:componentsNewDate];
}
```

But the console outputs is `2015-06-05 10:41:54.544 Test[1119:25066] begining of month: 2015-05-31 16:00:00 +0000`
I just looked the calendar, it should be 2015-06-01 but it shows 2015-05-31. And I did set firstWeekday to 2, so it's Monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are getting the right result. Depending on the time zone of your Xcode installation, the console will output a different date.

Try using a date formatter in `NSLog`.

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *firstMonday = [self beginningOfMonth:[NSDate date];
NSLog(@"First Monday of month: %@", [f stringFromDate:firstMonday]);
```

Comment: Correct. But how do I get the right NSDate from it?

Comment: The date *itself* does not change. It is just how you view it. If you change the time zone or daylight savings setting of the *formatter*, the *displayed* displayed date will be different but not the *actual* date.

Comment: So there is no way to get the actual NSDate from it, right? Even I set the correct time zone and daylight saving setting, right?

Comment: No. You are getting the actual date from it in your desired time zone.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. No matter what the NSDate shows, it's the actual date.